# Android Studio run configuration for ORMLite config generation

Tags: android, android-studio, ormlite

I'm using Android Studio and want to use ORMLite framework. ORMLite for Android has a mechanism for making DAO creation through [table config file](http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config).

How to setup additional Run Configuration in Android Studio for generating this config?

Comment: Look here also. This is how to set it up on Android Studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/31946807/976550

Answer (score 39):

I managed to do it, but it was a little bit tricky.

I have a class called DatabaseConfigUtil which extends OrmLiteConfigUtil, that I created just by following the ormlite official tutorial, so I'll just assume you did the same and also have that class. **Please note that you have to pass the complete path to the configuration file, instead of just the file name.** Nonetheless, here it is:

```
public class DatabaseConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
  private static final Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] {
    Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class, Class4.class
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
    writeConfigFile(new File("PATH/TO/ANDROID/PROJECT/src/main/res/raw/ormlite_config.txt"), classes);
  }
}
```

This is the class we want to execute in order to create the ormlite_config.txt.

In the Android Studio project navigation panel, right-click on the DatabaseConfigUtil.java and select "Run" (the option with the green arrow). If you don't have a Run Configuration created, it will create one for you.

Now, just edit the configuration

[image]

In the "Before launch" section, remove the Make. This is not problematic if in the raw folder you already have the file ormlite_config.txt, but if you don't, when you run the class, the project will compile which will fail because the ormlite_config.txt doesn't exist.

[image]

Now run the project again.

Everything should go smoothly now.

Cheers

---------------------------- ## ----------------------------

UPDATE:

Recently I had to work with ORMLite again and decided that this solution could be automated with a gradle plugin. Before creating my own, as the lazy developer that I am, I decided to check if anyone had attempted the same before. Thankfully, @snicolas did just that and you can find his plugin [here](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin). I've tried it, and it works reasonably well. It creates a task called `createORMLiteConfigFile*Variant*` that you can run to generate the file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have another problem. When I run DatabaseConfigUtil configuration ClassNotFoundException occurs: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.DatabaseConfigUtil`

Comment: Before you run, try to compile. And perhaps it is related to the classpath. You can check if in your run configuration, where it says "Use classpath of module", the correct project is selected, which should be your android project. Nevertheless I would suggest you delete your existing run configuration if you already have one and run again.

Comment: A compile did not work, I tried every module I have and I also tried a simple java library module to get it to work... doesn't work either. Any additional ideas to get rid of the ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: I've had to add the two libraries (core and android) from ORMLite) to the build.gradle file, like this: compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.46.jar') compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.46.jar').

Comment: After I've fixed the ClassNotFoundException I got the message "Could Not Find Raw Directory". I got that one because I was not placing the url in the File constructor. Instead I've passed the url directly in the writeConfigFile method. After adding the new File("..") I had to Rebuild the project and all worked fine! :)

Comment: Just notice, if you just want to use `writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt");` only, you should set `Working Directory` in `Edit Configurations` to `<YOUR-WORKING-DIR>/src/main`. ORMLite could find the raw directory automatically.

Comment: I did following tuning to make it work: 1) replaced "Make" with "Make, no error check" and 2) specified correct WORKDIR (i.e. the root directory of android project)
Thank you João!

Comment: To expand on @ZerayRice suggestion, you can use the `$MODULE_DIR$` variable in the `Working Directory` field to make this cross-platform and throw this run configuration in source control: `$MODULE_DIR$/src/main`

Comment: Following all these comments was a little tricky, so I collected them up into a new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30222996/112705

Comment: How to compile the java file in the android Studio i'm getting the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package..OrmliteDatabaseConfigUtil.

Answer (score 23):

Collecting up all the comments under @Joao's answer gave me this working solution:

1) Edit Configuration for your DB config file generator:

[image: edit configuration]

2) Configure the `Working directory` to be `$MODULE_DIR$/src/main`.

3) In `Before launch`, replace `Make` with `Make, no error check`

[image: working directory]

When you have these steps in place you can specify just the file name in your `OrmLiteConfigUtil` class:

```
public class DBConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {

    /**
     * To make this work in Android Studio, you may need to update your
     * Run Configuration as explained here:
     *   http://stackoverflow.com/a/17332546
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt", sClasses);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. For any one who is wondering, sClasses is the classes that you have annotated eg: private static final Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] {Workout.class};. You will also have to create the raw folder under the res folder before you run the config and also once you are successful, you can add the config file here: RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper( application, "sample_database.db", null, 3, R.raw.ormlite_config);

Comment: This is spot on, easy and in line with the official documentation of ORMLite, but more friendly.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue OP got for the ClassNotFoundException. The workaround for this is to temporarily to change the code to make the compiler to compile the project.

I had to remove the R.raw.ormlite_config value that I used in the DatabaseHelper class, which I am passing to the super().

```
public class DBConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
private static final Class<?>[] classes = new Class[] {Workout.class};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt",classes);
    }

}
```

My DBHelper class that extends the extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper needs to not use the raw folder yet. This helps in compiling the project successfully.

```
public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION,1);// R.raw.ormlite_config
}
```

[image]

1. compiled the project.
2. change the working directory to the app/src/main folder.
3. Changed the JRE to JDK1.8
4. Remove the Make from the Before launch section.
5. Run

Answer (score 5):

Ok I stumpled upon the same ClassNotFoundException like the OP. Here is how I solved it:

Short note: I have a library project and a main project and both are set up to with Gradle, that might be quite a difference as the previously called solution did not work for my setup.

So my steps to do:

1. I created the DatabaseConfigUtil class

   ```
   public class DatabaseConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
       public static final Class<?>[] MODELS = {Character.class, Party.class, Clazz.class};

       /**
        * This must be called as a stand alone app by a JRE instance and NOT by android.
        * It will create an ormlite config file that will make the reflection for annotation and more easier and faster.
        * <p/>
        * Make sure you have pathOfProject/build/classes/debug in your class path when running!
        * <p/>
        * Working class path:
        * <code>-classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/jconsole.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/home/martin/workspace/idea/Project/MainProject/libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar:/home/martin/workspace/idea/Project/MainProject/libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/martin/workspace/idea/Project/MainProject/build/classes/debug:/opt/android/platforms/android-16</code>
        *
        * @param args none will be used.
        * @throws Exception
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           writeConfigFile(new File("MODULENAME/src/main/res/raw/ormlite_config.txt"), MODELS);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Note the class path I used in my documentation: It is basically based on the normal classpath you get when you try to run the above class (just copy it)
3. Create a run configuration and add the classpath you just copied as `VM options`
4. Make sure you have removed every entry that contains "build/classes/production/MODULENAME"
5. Add the complete path of your "build/classes/debug" to the classpath
6. Compile and run the configuration.

You should see the output that the classes you defined in `MODELS` are created.

Side note: Joao Sousa said you should change the ORMlite source code. There is an easier method: The `writeConfigFile(fileName)` method seems to be broken in the new Gradle structure as it starts to look in the module root and goes up instead of going down to `src/main/res/raw` so I needed to use the other one where I could give a file object as parameter (see above code).

Final note: As I try to make a lot of stuff on one press, I created a second run configuration that is called "PROJECTNAME FULL" which will do a "make" than runs the ormlite run configuration and finally a second "MAKE".
The first make compiles the sources so that the ormlite configuration can be created and the second "make" makes sure that the new created config file is added to the newly created build which will be installed then. This "FULL" configuration doesn't need to run every time but at least once when you changed your model classes.

Comment: Regarding the usage of the alternative method

    writeConfigFile(File configFile, Class<?>[] classes)

silly me :D this solution is much "sexier"

Comment: Well it happens to everyone from time to time :D

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this because my DB classes were defined in a Java project external to my android project.  But the OrmLiteConfigUtil is defined in the ormlite-android library, and must be built in the android project itself.

It's OK, Gray plans ahead.  There's an overload of writeConfigFile that accepts File arguments specifying the search directory.

```
public class DatabaseConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      File conffile = new File("app/src/main/res/raw/ormlite_config.txt");
      File searchdir = new File("../jclip/tdb/src/main/java/");
      writeConfigFile(conffile, searchdir);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the "working directory" to /src/main of the project in "Edit Configurations"