# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'xyzcolumn' in table abctable

Tags: android, ormlite

I am getting the following exception only on Micromax A350.
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'xyzcolumn' in table abctable
I am using progaurd and i have added the progaurd rules for ormlite, but still problem persists.

This is happening when I generated apk from linux machine.

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/60

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'COLUMNNAME' in table TABLENAME
   at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.getFieldTypeByColumnName(TableInfo.java:155)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementBuilder.verifyColumnName(StatementBuilder.java:187)
   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.UpdateBuilder.updateColumnValue(UpdateBuilder.java:47)
```

Comment: Please post your SQL query.

Comment: both create table query and insert query..

Comment: I am getting this exception on update query.     updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("columnname", columnvalue); @Rohit5k2

Comment: What is your update query? Also post the complete logcat error.

Comment: updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("columnname", columnvalue); @Rohit5k2

Comment: Your table doesn't have any column with name `columnname`. If you have added it recently then uninstall the app and install again.

Comment: I have double checked the column name. It is there. And its not recently added, it is there from long time, but the problem came just today.@Rohit5k2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and these are the steps that happened to me that I think generated this problem:

1. I was always using just one table
2. Then I created a new table

After create this new table problems began with a colum of the first table created. Investigating I found that the problem was with the **ormlite_config.txt**. This config file only had information of the first table but nothing from the second table

So, the solution was, regenerate the [config file](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android)

How? [Using this answer of @joao-sousa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332546/2091181)

After that, all worked like a charm again