# Can't find ormlite config file

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to install ORMlite on my Android Studio project but I can't get the R.raw.ormlite_config file, I found this: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin  but still not working...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.stephanenicolas.ormgap:ormgap-plugin:1.0.12'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'ormgap'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

For my DataHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "solutis.db";


    private Dao<Demandes, Integer> simpleDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Demandes, Integer> simpleRuntimeDao = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, android.R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource){

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You will then need to create your database using the ORMLite config
>   file that will be generated during your build (note : you first need
>   to boostrap the system, get a file generated, then reference it.)

Refer Documentation Link : http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Config-Optimization

> ORMLite supports the loading of the data configurations from a text
>   configuration file. When a DAO is created, these configurations will
>   be used, removing the need for any annotation method calls entirely.
>
> 1. The OrmLiteConfigUtil utility class writes a `ormlite_config.txt` configuration file in the raw resource folder
>      `res/raw/ormlite_config.txt`. You will need to extend this class into
>      your own project along side your DatabaseHelper class. It should look
>      something like:

```
public class DatabaseConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have created a file like that, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298773/android-studio-run-configuration-for-ormlite-config-generation But it does'nt work too

Comment: Please follow the procedure as given in the documentation. I haven't tried it yet but excited to try this plugin. Also, share what problem you are facing now. I will try to solve.

Comment: That was hard to understand how to generate the file, but I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199875/compilation-of-ormliteconfig-file-in-android-studio

Comment: Is it a new feature ? it's working as well ? Now I installed it by using  Android Studio JRE

Comment: Annotations are slow in Android, and the makers of ORMLite have realized this, so they added the ability to run a java executable to generate a resource file that bypasses the need to check annotations at runtime in the android app.

Comment: I have also tried it. They have not given proper documentation and also not easy to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135263/discussion-between-mdg5435-and-ben).

Answer (score 0):

why you need this file? you can add this into
gradle..
`compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'`
 
and start working with db.

```
public class OrmLiteDbHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database_db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context mContext;

public OrmLiteDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    try {
        sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    sqLiteDatabase = database;
    try {

        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, TableSet.class);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
                      int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
try {
TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, TableSet.class, false);
onCreate(database, connectionSource);}catch (Exception e){  e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Comment: check this if it may be help..[link](https://horaceheaven.com/android-ormlite-tutorial/)

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi OP is using gradle plugin to boost DAOs creations & to improve performance on app startup. Refer this https://github.com/stephanenicolas/ormlite-android-gradle-plugin & http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Config-Optimization

Comment: @mdg5435 what is OP ?

Comment: Original Poster. The person who asked the question

Comment: @mdg5435 So I don't understand we are not obligated to use the file configuration ?

Comment: @mdg5435 You're talking about to boost ? Hmmm it make it faster or something like that ? Can I use the method of aj0822ArpitJoshi ?

Comment: Yeah you can use. And to make the process automated and need to make it faster then go for the gradle plugin.

Comment: @mdg5435 i also haven't use boost configuration before. so i dont  aware with it but according to you it make faster so i will try that .

Comment: Yeah. Try it. It is better.